# Flask form function doesn't work with Materialize button class

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm trying to create a website using Flask and Materialize.  Unfortunately, when I try using Materialize's button's class the form action doesn't work. All attempts I have made to get it to work end up changing the style of the image I want to use. Is this just not possible, or am I missing something?

Here is the application code:

```
@application.route("/test",methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    if request.method =='POST':
        print("It worked")
    return render_template("test.html", the_title="Test")
```

And here is the HTML page:

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block body %}

<form action="{{ url_for('test') }}" method="post">
    <!--This works-->
    <button name="test1" type="submit">Test1</button>

    <!--This doesn't work-->
    <a class="btn-large light-blue lighten-1"><Test2</a>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is a small typo -- an extra `<` before the link text. It should be:

```
<a class="btn-large light-blue lighten-1">Test2</a>
```

Even then, the link isn't really going to do much. You would need a `href` attribute for the link to actually point to something. For example:

```
<a href="/test" class="btn-large light-blue lighten-1">Test2</a>
```

Even then, this would make a `GET` request to the `/test` route rather than *submit* the form.

I suggest reading up on the Materialize documentation for buttons [here](https://materializecss.com/buttons.html):

> When you use a button to submit a form, instead of using a input tag,
> use a button tag with a type submit

So when you want to submit a form, you should be using a regular `button` instead of an `a` (hyperlink) tag. Using the same Materialize classes, the button and link would look identical.

You *could* use an `a` tag to submit the form, if that's what you really want -- you just need to add some JavaScript to add an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener), listening to the `click` event and your handler can then submit the form.

Here is an example, demonstrating the various possibilities.

- The first `button` is a regular HTML button that will submit the form
- The second `button` also submits the form, but applies Materialize styling
- The first link will make a `GET` request, rather than submit the form
- The second link will submit the form, with the help of an event listener that changes what the link should do when clicked

```js
document.getElementById('link2').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.currentTarget.parentNode.submit();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<form action="{{ url_for('test') }}" method="POST">

  <!-- This is a plain HTML button -->
  <button type="submit" id="btn1">Test1</button>

  <!-- This is a materialize button -->
  <button class="btn-large light-blue lighten-1" type="submit" id="btn2">Test2</button>

  <!-- These are links with materialize style -->
  <a class="btn-large light-blue lighten-1" id="link1" href="/test">Test3</a>
  <a class="btn-large light-blue lighten-1" id="link2">Test4</a>

</form>
```